# Microsoft Teams Calling - Hook to Read the Phone Number and Call an API With it

Tags: microsoft-teams, phone-call

We would like to have a hook in MS Teams that fires when a user makes an outbound call. The hook should read the phone number and pass it to an API. Depending on the result, it should either allow the call to go through or show an error message.

The idea is that the user calls a phone number along with a hashtag and a key value. Example: 555-555-5555#123456.

The hook should get the value after the hashtag and call an API with it to verify it, then return to the user.

We have looked at MS Graph APIs and can't find any baseline way to do it. We also looked at using an Azure Bot but the setup and sample code based on documentation does not work.

Has anyone done anything similar to this kind of hook based on an outbound Teams call?

Answer (score 0):

Currently, we don’t have such API to enable an app to hook to a user’s call to another phone number.

You'd be welcome to suggest this feature on the [Microsoft Teams Community](https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/forum/ad198462-1c1c-ec11-b6e7-0022481f8472).